# How to Find the number of times "3AM" was crossed since a certain datetime until now without a While loop?

Tags: python, datetime, youtube-api, python-datetime

Below you can find my code. I need to find the number of times a certain hour has passed since a given datetime. In my case, the datetime is 3 AM. I need to find the number of times 3 AM was crossed since the 'video_published_at' time. My colleagues suggested there had to be a more concise solution than this, even a one-liner. I thought my while loop that checks of every time adjusted_time.hour is 3 was the only way to do it, but could there be something easier on the eyes? Colleague says there must be a way without a while loop at all.

```
# Calculate the difference in hours since the video_published_at time
time_difference = todays_date - video_published_at
time_difference_secs = time_difference.total_seconds()
time_difference_hours = time_difference_secs / 3600

# Feedback/debug
print('Time Difference in Seconds: ' + str(time_difference_secs))
print('Time Differnce in Hours: ' + str(time_difference_hours))
print('')

# Calculate the number of times 3 AM CT was crossed during the 'time_difference_hours' by iteration
loop_count = 0
am_count = 0
adjusted_time = video_published_at_ct
# Loop through time difference
while loop_count <= time_difference_hours:
    adjusted_time = adjusted_time + timedelta(hours=1)
    # Feedback/debug
    print(str(loop_count) + ', ' + str(time_difference_hours))
    print(adjusted_time)
    print(adjusted_time.hour)       
    # Increase am_count every time the hour value hits 03:00
    if (adjusted_time.hour == 3):
        am_count = am_count + 1
    # Increment loop
    loop_count = loop_count + 1
```

Comment: Does CT stand for "Central Time" ? As in... USA's Central Time? I'm asking because on certain timezones, 3AM is the moment daylight savings ends (so you could have days with two 3AMs)

Comment: Yes, USA CT. Interesting. Really good info, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Below computes the number of days between two dates, but you get an extra 3am "crossing" if the publish date is before 3am and today's date is 3am or later:

```py
import datetime as dt

def times_crossed_3am(video_published_at, todays_date):
    count = (todays_date - video_published_at).days
    # Is published-on date before 3am on that day and today's date equal or greater than 3am on that day?
    if (video_published_at < video_published_at.replace(hour=3, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) and
        todays_date >= todays_date.replace(hour=3, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)):
        count += 1
    return count

# assuming ending on 3am is "crossing", but not starting on 3am.
print(times_crossed_3am(dt.datetime(2023,2,11,3), dt.datetime(2023,2,12,3)))
print(times_crossed_3am(dt.datetime(2023,2,11,2,59,59,999999), dt.datetime(2023,2,12,3)))
print(times_crossed_3am(dt.datetime(2023,2,11,2,59,59,999999), dt.datetime(2023,2,12,2,59,59,999999)))
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking but you could write this function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def count_times_3am_passed(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    current_date = start_date
    count = 0
    while current_date <= end_date:
        if current_date.hour == 3:
            count += 1
        current_date += timedelta(days=1)
    return count
```

Then using this function enter something similar to this:

```
start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2022-12-31'
print(count_times_3am_passed(start_date, end_date))
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This is good, and I could wrap my code in a function as well, but what I am really looking for is some way to do this without a while loop.